What is a Norm “Super Swiss”?
I have seen the term Norm “Super Swiss”,  what is it and how are the rules for getting norms different from other tournaments?

Rules for getting the norms are same as in all other tournaments. Point of super swiss tournament is, that it tries to guarantee by format that satisfying conditions for norm (according to same rules) will be possible.
Your performance is not the only condition for getting a norm - you need to play opponents from at least 2 federations different from your federation (1.4.3), at least some of your  opponent have to be titled (1.4.5), all your opponents need to be over some rating (1.4.6).
These conditions make getting a norm in usual swiss tournament harder - in the first round you may get an opponent with too low rating, you may have problems that your opponents aren't from enough different federations, etc.
So super swiss tournaments try to resolve these issues with adaptating conditions for player applications and by inviting players from other federations, for example Charlotte super swiss:

FIDE now requires a 40+ player Swiss norm for GM, IM, WGM, WIM titles.
Event will satisfy 1.43e “Super Swiss” foreigner requirement, making it more accommodating for players to earn norms by bypassing the normal foreign player requirement.
Open to players currently rated 2000+ FIDE.  No exceptions.

​

Not convinced this answer is correct as FIDE seem to wave the rule about "playing opponents from at least 2 federations" if the swiss have a lot of high rated players from many different federations.

@IanRingrose see point 1.4.3 in linked regulations - this rule can be waived for national, zonal and some swiss tournaments. But it has to be obeyed no matter what for at least one norm - so super swisses are useful, since they allow you to gain another norm through one of these exceptions.

That is not clear in your answer and I think it maybe the key attribute that define a "super swiss".
